# Angular resolver cancelling loading route component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an Angular resolver which is fetching data from an external system through a http call. Based on some condition I don't want the resolver to proceed and loading the component in the route. How can we manage this in Angular without using CanActivate. The reason is that I want to fetch this data only once for performance reasons.

Comment: Make use of Guard and CanActivate. Why not? It's not considered the bad practice to fetch some data inside Guard and decide whether to load route or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LocalStorage or SessionStorage or SharedService, set a flag to decide whether to route to the component or not.

Comment: Ok we will put some state on a shared angular service and pre-fetch the data in the guard already which is then eventually used in the resolver if it is allowed...

Comment: Agree we can use shared service as well